# Difference between self.variable name and classname.variable in python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to learn oop concepts and i chose python. As far as I know self.count and employee.count both calls the class variable count and they both should have same value. However, for the following code, I see that self.count is 1 and employee.count is 0.

```
class employee:
    count=0
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
        self.count=self.count+1
        print ("this method is executed")
        print (self.count)
        print (employee.count)
emp1=employee("John")
```

Comment: So they clearly are *not* the same variable; what, then, is your question?  Did you try making other `employee` objects?

Comment: No... self.count and employee.count both refers to the same class variable  count which I declared earlier

Comment: @vijay But only until you declare the instance variable `self.count`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If You want to count number of created `Employee`, You have to create method which will invoke to every objects at all (not individually).

To do that, create method and decorate her with `@staticmethod`. Notice that this method don't have `self` in parenthesies. Moreover create variable (here: `count`), which also invoke to every class object at all (without `self.` before).

Finally put our `count` variable inside `__init__` method with `+= 1` equation (than every time when new `Employee` will be created `__init__` will add +1 to our variable). But remember to add `Employee.` before `count` here, to count every single create `Employee` as a class population.

```
class Employee(object):
    count = 0

    @staticmethod
    def status():
        print(Employee.count)

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        Employee.count += 1
        print("this method is executed")
        print("Now, we have got", Employee.count, "Employees")


emp1 = Employee("John")
```

We can show up population number with :

```
print(emp1.count)
emp1.status()
print(Employee.count)
```

Comment: Please add some text to your answer explaining how this code snippet answers the OP's question

Comment: Here You go! Hope I helped You guys

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat subtle because of the line below:

```
self.count = self.count + 1
```

Here, the `self.count` on the left hand side and the `self.count` on the right hand side are **not the same thing**!

This line of code creates an instance variable on the `self` object (an `employee` instance) with a name (i.e. `count`) which shadows the variable of the same name that already exists on the class object (i.e. the `employee` class).

The right hand side is evaluated first, and that actually resolves the name `self.count` on the class object.  The presence of an instance attribute is actually checked for beforehand, but it doesn't exist yet since the instance attribute has not been bound.  Then, after the right hand side has been evaluated (i.e. the name `self.count` gets resolved, and `1` is added to it), the result of evaluation is bound to an instance attribute.

Both variables co-exist:

```
>>> emp1.count
1
>>> emp1.__class__.count
0
```

The key thing to learn here is Python's attribute lookup process: *the instance namespace is checked and then the class namespace is checked*.

Comment: So,  in the right hand side (self.count+1) , initially self.count is looked up and no instance variable is found. So, It took the value of class variable count (which is initialized earlier). After it found the value (0) it incremented the value and assigned it to instance variable . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

`emp1` is an *instance* of the class `employee`. Each instance has its own set of variables, called instance variables. These are the ones assigned as `self.var = ...` inside methods of the class.

If you try accessing `emp1.var` and this instance variable is not assigned, Python looks for a `var` variable attached to the class of `emp1`, meaning it looks up `employee.var`. These kind of variable are called a class variable, and they are defined the way you have defined `count=0` at the top of your class.

Now, in your example, `self.count=self.count+1`, the left-hand side assigns to the instance, so you are creating an instance variable called `count`. The right-hand side, however, looks up `self.count`, which does not yet exist as an instance variable, so `employee.count` is really used instead. This confusing behavior is avoided if you do not use the same variable name for both an instance variable and a class variable.