# The += Operator Not Acting As I Expect On Class Variable

Tags: python

I have this code:

```py
class Doh:
    ctr = 0;
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_num = self.ctr
        self.ctr += 1
d1 = Doh()
d2 = Doh()
print(f"d1: {d1.my_num}")
print(f"d2: {d2.my_num}")
```

I run it expecting d1 and d2 to have different values for `self.my_num` but they both come out 0:

```
d1: 0
d2: 0
```

So clearly I don't get how class variables work with +=.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You meant to update `Doh.ctr`

Comment: `ctr` is a static class variable, and is distinct from `self.ctr`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/1643973

Comment: The  += is working right. just do `print(d1.ctr)` to see that.

Comment: @Prune I'm not convinced that this question is asking that. This seems like a mutability question to me (how come after `b=0; a=b; b+=1`, `a != 1`?)

Comment: I *think* you have confused class and instance variables.  You set up a class variable, but never refer to it.  You use an instance variable, and complain that it doesn't affect its counterpart in another instance.

Comment: Not really a duplicate as my self-answer would have shown.

Comment: But I was unable to post the answer because the question was closed, prematurely in my opinion.

Comment: You state that you expect the two instance variables to have different values.  I infer that you expect the increment statement to update the class variable.  The duplicate I cited shows how to properly use those class variables.

Comment: Yes. That was close to my answer @Prune. Though my confused was caused by nested classes. I wrote up an explanation but still cannot post it.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Short answer. It should look like this:
```
class Doh:
    ctr = 0;
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_num = Doh.ctr
        Doh.ctr += 1
d1 = Doh()
d2 = Doh()
print(f"d1: {d1.my_num}")
print(f"d2: {d2.my_num}")
```

Long answer that confused me.  `Doh` in the above example was actually a class defined within another class in my code (call it `WrappingClass`.  So when I tried `Doh.ctr` I got a complaint that `Doh` wasn't found.

That was because it should have been `WrappingClass.Doh.ctr` in my code

Comment: I reopened, but it was immediately re-closed as a (different) dupe

Comment: @AdamSmithThis raises a meta question for me in that I do search for dupes before posting but never find anything close to what I'm asking.  Searching seems to be much more effective from Google than inside Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

This is a mutability problem. If you replace your `0` with a `[]` and start appending to it, you'll get the result you expect. However you can't mutate a number, you can only replace it with another one. While

```py
self.my_num = self.ctr
```

Does in fact save the same reference to both `self.my_num` and `self.ctr`, the next line

```py
self.ctr += 1
```

Replaces `self.ctr`s reference with a new (incremented) value.

Comment: This is not about mutability. Please refer to the answer from @wim for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369664/6890912